# I would like to get some suggestion regarding multiple ejb-jars in one ear

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, ear

I would like to get some advise. I have an application which consist of modules. A module is sliced to 3 parts, so every module has:
- libraries (shared jars, DTOs, beans)
- swing stuffs
- ejb stuffs

The whole is packaged in one ear file and it may contains many ejb jars, currently 3. To handle separated the ejb jars of the particular modules of my application is, I think, the easiest way to manage the whole. Later I would like to use OSGi to handle the modules. But, this is the future.

Every ejb jar has own persistence.xml and it works. I can deploy it, the hibernate creates the tables and I can use my application. But I have that feeling this is not the best or proper solution to handle this "multiple ejb jars in one ear" situation. I would like to know what is the best or proper solution or what is your suggestion.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you do it is actually the best OO-solution: you seperate your concerns.

Moreover you also have more flexibility in the current situation: you can leave out or change one of the ejb jar files and your application will still deploy and keep working.